# meta name "refresh" doesn't work

Tags: html

I have this:

```
<head>
  <!-- ..... -->
      <meta name="refresh" content="3" />
  <!-- ..... -->
```

For some reason, it's not redirecting to itself each 3 seconds. Nothing happens at all. How can it be?

Answer (score 0):

wrong attribute used. It should be: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">`

Comment: @Joddy well my tests shows different, but maybe you know better.

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
</head>
```